# Custom class to string

Tags: delphi

Hi I've created a custom class called Tperson. I'd like to convert this to a string so I can save it to an array( of type Tperson) and display in a string grid.

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TPerson = class(Tobject)
  public
    Fname   : string;
    Fage    : integer;
    Fweight : integer;
    FHeight : integer;
    FBMI    : real;

    function GetBMI(Fweight,Fheight:integer) : real;
    procedure create(Fname:String;fage,fweight,fheight:integer);overload;
    procedure Persontostr(Fname:string;Fage,Fheigth,Fweight:integer;FBMI:real);overload;
  end;

implementation

{ TPerson }



procedure TPerson.create(Fname: String; fage, fweight, fheight: integer);
begin
    Fname := '';
    Fage := 0;
    Fweight := 0;
    FHeight := 0;
    FBMI := 0;
end;

function TPerson.GetBMI(Fweight, Fheight: integer): real;
begin
  result := (Fweight/Fheight) * (Fweight/Fheight);
end;

procedure TPerson.Persontostr(Fname:string;Fage,Fheigth,Fweight:integer;FBMI:real);
begin

end;

end.
```

Comment: Could you explain "convert this to a string so I can save it to an array( of type Tperson)" please? This doesn't quite make sense as a requirement.  There should be no need to convert it to a string to add the object to an array, instead it could be added to an array (or TList) of TPerson.  Displaying in a string grid can extract strings or values it converts to strings from the TPerson object itself.

Comment: What you're doing in your constructor is totally unnecessary in Delphi, because the object's memory is filled with zeros at construction time, and it means all number fields will be 0, string fields will be empty strings, pointer fields will be nil and automatically.  On the other hand what you should do is to call the inherited Create constructor to properly initialize the object; just add this line: inherited Create;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which fields do you want to convert to string?

If all then you can do something like:

```
function TPerson.ToString: string;
begin
  Result := Format('%s, %d years, %d kg, %d cm, BMI: %.f', [FName, FAge, FWeight, FHeight, FBMI]);
end;
```

What do you want with the procedure Persontostr. It looks like a setter procedure to me. Although the name implies an other function.

Further, you should make your fields private. So you can add properties. BMI should be readonly:

```
type
  TPerson = class(Tobject)
  private
    // Object fields, hidden from outside.
    FName   : string;
    FAge    : integer;
    FWeight : integer;
    FHeight : integer;

    // Getter function for calculated fields.
    function GetBMI: Real; // Calculates BMI.
  public
    // Constructor, used to initialise the class
    constructor Create(const AName: string; const AAge,AWeight, AHeight: integer);

    // Properties used to control access to the fields.
    property Name: string read FName;
    property Age: Integer read FAge;
    property Weight: Integer read FWeight;
    property Height: Integer read FHeight;
    property BMI: Real read GetBMI;
  end;
```

Comment: I'm at school level so the format is not that important, but I understand. thank you for the help .